# how to get Soft key input for the enter and delete/backspace regardless of the soft keyboard the user uses

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want a way to detect the backspace and the enter key strokes.
The most recommended way I found was the OnKeyListener. but, that isn't working for me. I tried Logging and turns out it just wasn't detecting any keystrokes.

Even it's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener#:%7E:text=Key%20presses%20in,input%20key%20presses.) says it won't get triggered always.

I use Microsoft's swiftkey keyboard.
I also got a suggestion for addTextChengedListener. but, that won't detect backspaces. So, can't use it.

here's the code that isn't working -

```
editText.setOnKeyListener { view, i, keyEvent ->    //not working
    Log.i(TAG, "onKeyListener working")
    when (i) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER -> {
            fileChanged(
                position,
                editText.text.toString(),
                note.isAListItem,
                note.listItemIsChecked
            )
            listAdder(position)
            true
        }
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL -> {
            fileChanged(
                position,
                editText.text.toString(),
                note.isAListItem,
                note.listItemIsChecked
            )
            if (editText.text.isNullOrEmpty() && position != 0) {
                listRemover(position)
            }
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Also, I think the code is being discarded while compiling because the setOnKeyListener function doesn't get highlighted [yellow highlight] as the addTextChangedListener function. This is after the code was compiled. see below -

[image: yellow highlight]

Comment: `addTextChangedListener` is an extension function that is why it's highlighted with yellow colour. If `addTextChangedListener` doesn't work, though it must always notify you about changes in the text of the given input field, there is unlikely will be anything else you can use. Are you sure `addTextChangedListener` isn't working?

Comment: the addTextChangedListner is working and it also provides log messages (look at the log command in the image above.) to the log. But, at the same time, the setonKeyListener's log function (look at the code's second line) isn't working. I think I should mention that I am using this inside a recyclerview.

Comment: If `addTextChangedListener` is working then it is the only solution I can think of especially considering that `OnKeyListener` documentation mentions that "a software input method **has no obligation** to trigger this listener."